# Removing multiple recurring text from pandas rows`

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, data-science, text-processing

I am having a pandas dataframe which consists of scraped articles from websites as rows. I have 100 thousand articles in the similar nature.

Here is a glimse of my dataset.

```
text
0   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
1   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
2   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
3   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
4   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
5   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
6   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
7   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
8   which brings not only warmer weather but also the unsettling realization that the year is more than halfway over. So
for those who werent as productive as they would have liked during the first half of 2018
28  for those who werent as productive as they would have liked during the first half of 2018
29  for those who werent as productive as they would have liked during the first half of 2018
30  for those who werent as productive as they would have liked during the first half of 2018
31  for those who werent as productive as they would have liked during the first half of 2018
32  for those who werent as productive as they would have liked during the first half of 2018
```

Now, these are intials of each texts and they are repetitive. The main text lies after these texts.

Is there any way or a function possible, which identifies these texts and swipe them out in a few lines of code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Swipe them out"? You simply want to remove these phrases?

Comment: no, drop duplicates can be applied to rows only, which are all different as the main text lies after these recurring text. The scrapping of different from same website corresponds to these similar recurring text.

Comment: @HarvIpan, did you get my point, I can clarify more, if you want

Comment: Do you know these phrases before hand?

Comment: I can extract a few, but I have thousands or more like these. I believe, thats why I am looking for smart approach which works automatic extraction.

Comment: You should look into [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/) .

Comment: I have been looking into the same from 2 hours, including regex. I am a naive, I am sorry

Comment: Do you want to remove 1. strings are exact duplicates, or 2. strings that are very similar but not exact duplicates? Case 2 is much harder.

Comment: @polm23 Yes, I want to remove, strings that are similar in different rows as above which exists in some rows and then others as well in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `difflib` somehow, for example:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> a = "my mother always told me to mind my business" 
>>> b = "my mother always told me to be polite"
>>> s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,a,b)
>>> s.find_longest_match(0,len(a),0,len(b))
```

Output:

```
Match(a=0, b=0, size=28)
```

Where `a=0` means that the matching sequence starts at character `0` in string `a`, and `b=0` means that the matching sequence starts at character `0` for string `b`.

Now if you do:

```
>>> b.replace(a[:28],"")
```

The ouptu will be:

```
'be polite'
```

And if you choose to do `c = s.find_longest_match(0,len(a),0,len(b))` then `c[0] = 0`, `c[1] = 0` and `c[2] = 28`.

You can read more about it here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Comment: I am thankful for your time, but I can also do that in different, I also thought of the same approach, but its not scalable to my need.

Comment: I upvoted it, but I am looking for some more guidance and more intuitive approach, do you have any another idea

Comment: You could first sort the list, and then apply the method betwen strings `i` and `i+1`, this way you only compare 0 and 1, 1 and 2.... if you need to get the original order you can sort the indexes instead of the values. This would only help with similarities in the leading characters though :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove strings that are **exactly the same**, sort your dataframe and then go through it in order. (This is similar to what Nerdrigo mentioned in a comment.)

```
sents = ... # sorted dataframe
out = [] # stuff here will be unique
for ii in range(len(sents) - 1):
    if sents[ii] != sents[ii + 1]:
        out.append(sents[ii])
```

If you want to remove sentences that are **very similar but not exactly the same**, the problem is much harder and there's no easy solution. You need to look into **locality-sensitive hashing** or **near-duplicate detection**. The [datasketch](https://ekzhu.github.io/datasketch/) library may be helpful.

---

Based on your comment I think I finally get it - you want to remove a **common prefix**. In that case modify the above code to be like this:

```
sents = ... # sorted dataframe
out = [] # cleaned sentences go here
lml = -1 # last match length
for ii in range(len(sents) - 1):
    # first check if the match from the last iteration still works
    if sents[ii][:lml] == sents[ii+1][:lml] and sents[ii][:lml + 1] != sents[ii+1][:lml + 1]:
        # old prefix still worked, chop and move on
        out.append(sents[ii][lml:])
        continue

    # if we're here, it means the prefix changed
    ml = 1 # match length
    # find the longest matching prefix
    while sents[ii][:ml] == sents[ii+1][:ml]:
        ml += 1

    # save the prefix length
    lml = ml
    # chop off the shared prefix
    out.append(sents[ii][ml:])
```

Comment: Really sorry in understanding, my idea is the same to remove same strings which are occurring in the beginning. I dont want to remove them competely as the main text starts after the recurring texts in the rows in the df.

Comment: I rand this, the length got 1/20 of the intitial dataframe, I want to keep the length same as all of them are different

Comment: so I can say that, these are the different reoccurring patterns which came out output, 1/20 around of all df. but all are different as the articles content is after these texts