# Reading text files from subfolders and folders and creating a dataframe in pandas for each file text as one observation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following architecture of the text files in the folders and subfolders.

I want to read them all and create a df. I am using this code, but it dont work well for me as the text is not what I checked and the files are not equivalent to my counting.

[image: folders- level 1]
[image: files in first folder and so on]

```
l = [pd.read_csv(filename,header=None, encoding='iso-8859-1') for filename in glob.glob("2018_01_01/*.txt")]
main_df = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
main_df = main_df.T
for i in range(2):
    l = [pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, encoding='iso-8859-1',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE) for filename in glob.glob(str(foldernames[i+1])+ '/' + '*.txt')]
    df = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
    df = df.T
    main_df = pd.merge(main_df, df)
```

[file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qiaggsLDNJfLlz45cURN1q7XMCkadQBQ)

Comment: do all your files have the same structure, i.e., the same columns, so you can simply concatenate them?

Comment: yes, they are all text files, there are no columns, like simple txt files

Comment: I just added an answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Would you mind checking it?

Comment: would you mind providing how one of your txt files look like?

Comment: yes, please , I am updating my question

Comment: and based on that piece of text that is not structured as comma separated values, what is the DataFrame structured you are expecting to have...?

Comment: A dataframe with only one column, each text file as one observation

Comment: so just to see if I understand well. What you want in the end is a dataframe with 200 records (rows) and 1 column which name is `observation`?

Comment: yes, If I have 200 text files in all my folders and subfolders

Comment: I just updated my answer once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming those directories contain txt files in which information have the same structure on all of them:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['observation'])

path = '/path/to/directory/of/directories/'

for directory in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as f:
                observation = f.read()
                current_df = pd.DataFrame({'observation': [observation]})
                df = df.append(current_df, ignore_index=True)
```

Once all your files have been iterated, `df` should be the `DataFrame` containing all the information in your different txt files.

Comment: I have to update this - ,header=None, encoding='iso-8859-1',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE

Comment: but still, I have unstrucured dataframe , which has 1800 columns and 5 rows, last columns and rows are NaN and in the folder I have just used 4 subfilder not all to save time, and there should be 200 files right now

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 0 - if I skip quoting as csv part

Comment: @AymanAlawin, what if we add the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` parameter

Comment: but still, I have unstrucured dataframe , which has 1800 columns and 5 rows, last columns and rows are NaN and in the folder I have just used 4 subfilder not all to save time, and there should be 200 files right now

Comment: it should work, but, here is a problem -  13                 current_df = df.DataFrame({'observation': observation})
Error is - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Comment: I already did that, it threw this error, then ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: @AymanAlawin, hopefully it will work now. My update `[observation`.

Comment: you are a hero my friend, i added this , index=[0] in surrent_df and it all read all the stuffs as I wanted. I know this is something very helpful. Many thanks for you time, brother. God bless you

Comment: Here is another query on the similar dataframe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485289/removing-multiple-recurring-text-from-pandas-rows.

Comment: I have also one question, like. 

I can remove number as follows
main_df['text'] = main_df['text'].str.replace('\d+', '')
but when I move to next step to convert to lower it says , cant be done for floats, how i can remove floats in similar manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176617/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-ayman-alawin).

Comment: instead of  reading  text file  I'd like to read excel file  any  help please I  have  the same  folder structure as u

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a for loop. But before that, you need to give a sequenced name to all the files like 'fil_0' within 'fol_0', 'fil_1' within 'fol_1', 'fil_2' within 'fol_2' and so on. That would facilitate the use of a for loop:

```
dataframes = []
import pandas as pd
for var in range(1000):
    name  = "fol_" + str(var) + "/fil_" + str(var) + ".txt"
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(name)) # if you need to use all the files at once
    #otherwise
    df = pd.read_csv(name) # you can use file one by one
```

It will automatically create dataframes for each file.

Comment: sorry, I have thousands of files

Comment: Thanks for your time, aboe answer is what I was looking for.